# How do I change the color of the selected icon in BottomNavigationView using Activity instead of Fragment in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I'm using activity instead of fragment in `BottomNavigationView`. I want to change the color of the active activity icon when switching from one activity to another. But somehow I could not. How do I change the color of the selected icon?

**Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_playlist"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_playlist_play_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_playlist"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_profile"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true"/>
</menu>
```

selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

Layout BottomNavigationView XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_bottombar"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_bottombar"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" >
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

MainActivity :

```
  BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_playlist:
                        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Playlist.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        onStop();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Profile.class);
                        startActivity(b);
                        onStop();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Playlist:

```
   BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_playlist:
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        Intent a = new Intent(Playlist.this,Profile.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        onStop();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        Intent b = new Intent(Playlist.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(b);
                        onStop();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Profile:

```
BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        Intent a = new Intent(Profile.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        onStop();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_playlist:
                        Intent b = new Intent(Profile.this,Playlist.class);
                        startActivity(b);
                        onStop();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You shoudl read https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/

Comment: I have reviewed the information in the link you provided. However, the color of the selected icon still does not change.